# Using subquery to find sum for individuals for reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum, subquery

I'm trying to calculate the sum of unposted transactions for individuals. I'm thinking I need a subquery to do this but I receive the

> *error* **(Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.)**
>   I should have known that I would get that error but I'm not sure how to tie in the table. Here's the full query:

```
select ar.id_num, 
nm.last_name, 
nm.first_name, 
am.ADDR_LINE_1, 
am.ADDR_LINE_2, 
am.CITY, 
am.STATE, 
am.ZIP,
nm.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
ar.ar_bal_to_dte,
ar.UNAPPLIED_FIN_AID, 
lt.Last_term_end_date
,ar.ar_bal_to_dte + ar.UNAPPLIED_FIN_AID as 'Unapplied Aid',
 case when getdate()<= arm.end_dte then 'Dir Deposit' else 'Check' end as 'pmt type',
'Unposted Charges' = (select SUM (trans_amt) from TRANS_HIST where SOURCE_CDE = '@C' AND SUBSID_CDE = 'AR' group by ID_NUM )   
from   SUBSID_MASTER ar left outer join ccsc_last_term_end_date_v lt on ar.ID_NUM = lt.id_num
left outer join SUBSID_MASTER_EPAY_ACCT arm ON AR.ID_NUM = arm.ID_NUM
inner join TRANS_HIST th ON AR.ID_NUM = th.ID_NUM 
JOIN NAME_MASTER nm ON ar.ID_NUM = nm.ID_NUM
JOIN ADDRESS_MASTER am on ar.ID_NUM = am.ID_NUM
where ar.SUBSID_CDE = 'AR'
and ar.AR_BAL_TO_DTE < 0 and am.ADDR_CDE = '*LHP' 
order by lt.Last_term_end_date
```

Does anyone have some advice for me? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only subquery in the query:

```
'Unposted Charges' = (select SUM(trans_amt) from TRANS_HIST where SOURCE_CDE = '@C' AND SUBSID_CDE = 'AR' group by ID_NUM )
```

First, this looks really awkward.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Use square braces:

```
[Unposted Charges] = (select SUM(trans_amt) from TRANS_HIST where SOURCE_CDE = '@C' AND SUBSID_CDE = 'AR' group by ID_NUM )
```

The problem is the `GROUP BY`.  It returns a different row for each `ID_NUM`, hence the error.

One easy fix to the syntax problem is:

```
[Unposted Charges] = (select SUM(trans_amt) from TRANS_HIST where SOURCE_CDE = '@C' AND SUBSID_CDE = 'AR')
```

However, you probably intend:

```
[Unposted Charges] = (select SUM(th.trans_amt)
                      from TRANS_HIST th
                      where th.SOURCE_CDE = '@C' AND
                            th.SUBSID_CDE = 'AR' AND
                            th.ID_NUM = ar.ID_NUM
                     )
```

Comment: Mr Gordon always appears at SQL case..  (y)

Answer (score 0):

A nice alternative to the subselect would be to join to a derived table of

... `INNER JOIN (SELECT TH.ID_NUM, SUM(TH.TRANS_AMT) AS UNPOSTED_CHARGES FROM TRANS_HIST TH WHERE TH.SOURCE_ID = '@C' AND TH.SUBSID_CDE = 'AR' GROUP BY TH.ID_NUM) DT ON DT.ID_NUM = AR.ID_NUM` ...

So then you can just use `DT.UNPOSTED_CHARGES` in your select list.